# Delphi: hook TImageList to load images on demand

Tags: delphi

Is it possible to hook into a TImageList or make a descendant, to catch when an image is requested from it so I can manually load it each time? (specifically when ListView requests the images)

Comment: Theoretically it is possible bit I wouldn't recommend you to do so. Why? The main purpose of TImageList control is to hold commonly used images in memory so that they are immediately available to various controls without needing to wait for them to be loaded from some files. Now you are probably thinking that TListView request image information from ImageList only when certain List Item is shown for the first time but you would be wrong. TListView is requesting image information from TImageList on every redraw. And these happen much more often than you may think. ...

Comment: ... Redraws can happen when you scroll around your list, when parts of your list view has been obstructed and revealed by some other control, when part of the form that List View is on is being redrawn and so on. If ListView would have to wait for some images to be loaded every time it needs them it would seriously impact its rendering performance and hog entire UI.

Comment: So why are you even thinking about this? What problems are you facing now that you would need to load images to Image List on demand? Perhaps you are trying to solve your problem in the wrong way.

Comment: I have a LV that needs to display around 150K items, all with an Icon. Loading all of the (different) images to an ImgList is out of the question, but I thought maybe I can just dynamically load the picture on request as the LV requests it while the user scrolls through, and avoid the hassle of custom drawing.

Comment: It will be a little more involved but item count is no problem for a [virtual list view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/list-view-controls-overview#virtual-list-view-style). VCL [link](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCustomListView.OwnerData).

Comment: The problem is loading the images in the imagelist, it would crash after 10K GDI handle limit.

Comment: One option would be to owner draw the items and not associating an image list at all. Another would be to investigate LVM_SETCALLBACKMASK, I'm not sure if that could be used to fake a smaller image list to account for all the items and continuously switching images. Well, the latter doesn't sound good even if it'll work...

Comment: Do you really need 150000 images for 150000 items?

Comment: Not 150k, but many more than 10K. I resorted to assigning a dummy imglist with item.iconindex always at 0 then redrawing the corresponding icon on CustomDrawItem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Both are native controls and images in list view controls is not a VCL feature but an API feature.

When you set images of a `TListView`, what VCL does is to call [`ListView_SetImageList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-listview_setimagelist) with the image list's handle. Consequently, when the [list view control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/list-view-controls-overview) requests an image, it will be from the [native control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/image-lists). No VCL code will run.

Comment: While TImageList is a wrapper for windows Image List there is nothing stopping you of replacing the default Image List code wit your own. In fact there are several third party Image List control replacements which do just that and thus extend way past what default TImageList control can do. Forinstace I have once seen a TImageList replacement which supports loading of images from many more image and texture formats that original TImageList does. Even more I have seen TImageList that instead of storing images in memory stores then in Video Memory as DirectX image atlass ...

Comment: .. All of them can work with all standard Delphi control that can connect to default TImageList

Comment: @Silver - You did not understand the answer, the list view does not care timagelist, it cannot even if it wanted to. All it knows is a image list handle, no code on timagelist side can run when it retrieves an image, however advanced it is.

Comment: Except of course by detouring, which makes almost anything possible.